# django not rendering csrf_token cant see why

Tags: django, django-csrf

What is wrong here:

```
var form = $('<form action="{% url 'st_forms.views.getFormMetaData'%}" method="POST"/>');
form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="formCode" value="'+formCode+'"/>'));
form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="action" value="search"/>'));
form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/>'));
form.appendTo($(document.body)).submit();
```

when page is rendered django nothing puts on place `{{ csrf_token }}`

Comment: I saw what is a problem :) Forgot to put RequestContext(request) in view :)

Comment: There is also a template tag {% csrf_token %}.

Comment: Why not `$('{% csrf_token %}').val()`?

Comment: because you need to put RequestContext(request) in view. Now django can make csrf token